# When I ran in the Linux jar file is not working why?

Tags: java, hive, jar, executable-jar

I am using Java 11.

when I running the source code in intelligence it was working very well but when I packed jar flie after that I running the jar file it show the error

> "Java.lang.classnamefoundexception: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"

when I running the jar I use this command

```
"Java-jar test.jar"
```

I don't understand I run in local(intellij) is good work
but I used in Linux env it show above the error
if know the why is wrong please give me a hand
I want to add up image I can't do it because of my company policy...

Comment: When packaging, you need to package org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver into the jar file. 
Otherwise, you need to use `-cp` to specify HiveDriver

Comment: hi thanks to reply when I make the jar I use intellij so when I make it jar is it automatically included all imported libraries right?

Comment: ! I'm not sure how to use the intellij, but the dependent jar packages or class files must be packaged together. 
Otherwise, you must specify the location of the dependent package through -classpath

Comment: Imagine you have a toolbox, you can use it to pick a lock, but the wrench must be in the toolbox, otherwise, you have to borrow the wrench from your neighbor