# what is it wrong? about jar file in linux running

Tags: linux, hive, jar, executable-jar

0

I am using Java 11

when I running the source code in intelligence it was working very well but when I packed jar flie after that I running the jar file it show the error

like

"Java.lang.classnamefoundexception: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"

when I running the jar I use this command

"Java-jar test.jar"
the part of source code is "Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")

I don't understand I run in local(intellij) is good work

but I used in Linux env it show above the error

if know the why is wrong please give me a hand

I want to add up image I can't do it because of my company policy... thanks

I searched all the site

Comment: Pls do not post same questions multiple times - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75331731/when-i-ran-in-the-linux-jar-file-is-not-working-why